# c# node struct circular dependency in custom LinkedListNode structure

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, linked-list, circular-dependency, unsafe

So, I am trying to write a new linked list in c# that will behave properly in an unsafe context so I can pass it off to a multithreaded process.  Unfortunately, even though all I need is a constant size pointer, this is creating a circular dependency.  I would rather not make this a class, and I'm not sure how that would behave in an unsafe context.  I also don't think that the interface solution will work in my case as it is literally a pointer to itself.  Also, when I try to write it it complains about some of the code being managed yet... how do I fix that? Here is the code snippet:

```
struct UnsafeLinkedListNode<T>
{
    public T value;
    unsafe public UnsafeLinkedListNode<T>* next;
    unsafe public UnsafeLinkedListNode<T>* prev;
}

class UnsafeLinkedList<T>
{

    unsafe public UnsafeLinkedListNode<T>* head = null;
    unsafe public UnsafeLinkedListNode<T>* tail = null;
    public ulong count;
    public void AddAfter(T value)
    {
        UnsafeLinkedList<T> temp = new UnsafeLinkedList<T>();
        temp.value = value;
        AddAfter(temp);
    }
    public void AddAfter(UnsafeLinkedListNode<T>* value)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            if(head !=null)
            {
                value.prev = tail;
                value.next = null;
                tail.next = value;
                count++;

            }
            else
            {
                value.next = null;
                value.prev = null;
                head = value;
                tail = value;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any circular dependency (except the self-referencing ``UnsafeLinkListNode<T>`` but that is normal for a linked list). However, I doubt this code will actually compile: you are calling ``AddAfter()`` with an ``UnsafeLinkedList<T>`` value but it expects a pointer to an ``UnsafeLinkListNode<T>`` value.

Comment: The circular dependency is in that first struct, also thanks, I completely missed that I already grabbed the address.  I've updated that.  How do I fix the circular dependency though?

Comment: Actuall, not using a generic does fix the managed code error, and I am no longer getting the error, but how do I make this work with a generic type then? struct UnsafeLinkedListNode
{
    public int value;
    unsafe public UnsafeLinkedListNode* next;
    unsafe public UnsafeLinkedListNode* prev;
}

Comment: I am actually curious, why can't you use array list / list for passing around data? It's both more memory efficient as well as more performant. Plus its easier to pass around as well.

Comment: Also, you are not assigning `value.value = something` so that could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the circular dependency and code management issues.  Finally solved it after 3 days, and then within minutes of posting.  Unfortunately there is still an issue trying to get the address of the node for some reason, but here is the solution to **THIS** problem:

```
struct UnsafeLinkedListNode
{
    public EncodedData value;
    unsafe public UnsafeLinkedListNode* next;
    unsafe public UnsafeLinkedListNode* prev;
}

class UnsafeLinkedList
{

    unsafe public UnsafeLinkedListNode *head = null;
    unsafe public UnsafeLinkedListNode *tail = null;
    public ulong count { get; private set; }
    unsafe public void AddAfter(EncodedData value)
    {
        UnsafeLinkedListNode temp = new UnsafeLinkedListNode();
        temp.value = value;
        AddAfter(&temp);
    }
    unsafe public void AddAfter(UnsafeLinkedListNode* value)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            if(head !=null)
            {
                value->prev = tail;
                value->next = null;
                tail->next = value;
                count++;

            }
            else
            {
                value->next = null;
                value->prev = null;
                head = value;
                tail = value;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```